# AngularJS - how to get the parameter from URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass the parameters to the AngularJS controller.

**AngularJs Routes**

```
$routeProvider.when('/post-ads/', {
            templateUrl: "ui/view/post-ads.php",
            controller: "adPostController",
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })

        $routeProvider.when('/post-ads/:category/:subcategory', {
            templateUrl: "ui/view/ad-details.php",
            controller: "adPostController",
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
```

**AdPostController**

```
adPostController.$inject = ['ApiService', '$scope'];
    function adPostController(ApiService, $scope, $routeParams) {
        console.log("im here");
        console.log($routeParams.category, $routeParams.subcategory);
    }
```

**HTML a href**

```
<a href="#/post-ads/automobile/car>click</a>
```

**Error**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your have to change:

```
adPostController.$inject = ['ApiService', '$scope'];
    function adPostController(ApiService, $scope, $routeParams) {
        console.log("im here");
        console.log($routeParams.category, $routeParams.subcategory);
    }
```

To:

```
adPostController.$inject = ['ApiService', '$scope', '$srouteParams'];
    function adPostController(ApiService, $scope, $routeParams) {
        console.log("im here");
        console.log($routeParams.category, $routeParams.subcategory);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
adPostController.$inject = ['ApiService', '$scope', '$routeParams'];
```